# Prevent standard user from installing "current-user" software in a normal way?

Tags: security, group-policy, uac

I have a specific problem, as you know standard user do have the ability to install "current-user" software, e.g "Viber" and many others.

I want to restrict standard users from installing "current-user" software, I searched the solutions but can not find the proper/normal way to do it.

One solution blocks all software install, even for administrators.
Other solutions I found aren't proper solutions.

I want to restrict the ability to install "current-user" software by using UAC (I think it must be proper way, like normal software do asks for admin password, I want same for "current-user" software, UAC to ask for admin password.)

What is the solution to this issue, how do you normally implement it in domain environment ?

Thanks, hope I explained my problem well, please only answer if you know the answer to exact problem.

Answer (score 2):

"Current User" installs don't require any privilege that the user wouldn't need for normal work. There is no difference between an installer tool creating a file, and a word processor doing that.

"All users" installs require the admin password only because the directories they write to are not writable for the current user.

UAC comes into the picture when an user requests permission to do something they aren't allowed to, but as long as users are permitted to save their work into their personal folder, they are allowed to create files and directories, and no more specific permission exists that can be revoked.

Comment: UAC will not come into the picture with some group policy enforced behaviors but yes, this is a good description of how the mechanism works. :)

Comment: This doesn't in any way shape or form answer the question.  I only says "you can't" (which is not true).

Comment: I understand what you are saying, now my question is how should I normally prevent users from installing e.g "Viber" ? 
Should I use Group Policy - Admin Templates > System > "Don't run specified Windows Applications" ? 
or how do you recommend to prevent running those software without admin rights?

Comment: @GeorgeG, your best chance is to stop these programs from working, e.g. by identifying their network traffic and blocking it in the firewall.

Answer (score 1):

### DisableUserInstalls Method

There is a registry key that might work for you.

Navigate to (or create) the key:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Installer`

Create a new DWORD value:
`DisableUserInstalls`

- 1 = no way Jose
- 0 = normal operation

[This link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/disableuserinstalls?redirectedfrom=MSDN) has more information on the topic.

Keep in mind that with this method.. *if* a program doesn't use MSI and is tricky enough.. there is no way for Windows to know that it is an installer program.

### AppLocker Method

There is also a feature introduced with Windows 7 called ***AppLocker*** which can allow you to whitelist or blacklist specific applications and usage of specific DLLs by applications.  [More on that here](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-8-applocker-step-by-step-guide).

Keep in mind that with this method, unless you use a whitelist only.. there are probably fairly simply methods around it (I am guessing this and don't know that for certain).  A blacklist would be more simple to manage from an IT perspective I think.  It depends on your users and the level of control that you want to exert.

You will need to play with these two methods to see which one works better for you.  I hope one of them gets the job done.

### Comments

I ***did*** read that you wanted a UAC popup.  Not sure if that will happen here.  Please read @SimonRichter answer.. it is a nice explanation of UAC.

I also read `please only answer if you know the answer to exact problem` ... here in SuperUser, this sort of statement might prevent you from getting the only answer that will work.

I mean no offense but ***if you don't like an answer, DON'T ACCEPT IT.  Thats how it works here.***  I know it seems odd (since you asked the question) but your question is for future users too who might want other solutions to the problem.